# Cant automate Amazon.com signout using Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium

I'm trying to do a simple selenium java automation for automating "sign in and sign out of amazon.com site". I'm able to sign in using element locator techniques, like XPath and CSS selector. But for signout, I'm thrown with ElementNotInteractable exception.

Below is the code that I tried(posting the code segment of signout alone).

```
WebElement element1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//header/div[@id='navbar']/div[@id='nav-belt']/div[3]/div[1]/a[1]/span[1]"));
element1.click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='nav-item-signout']")).click();
```

I have tried the above code segment with different element locator techniques like CSS selector and etc, but no luck.
Kindly suggest if I can find and click the sign-out link in the flyout menu by any other method.
Thanks.

Comment: try to put wait before logout element load

Comment: Hi if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can try below code in which explicit wait is implemented so it will wait for the element to click

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
WebElement element1 =driver.findElement(By.xpath("//header/div[@id='navbar']/div[@id='nav- 
       belt']/div[3]/div[1]/a[1]/span[1]"));
element1.click();
ele2=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='nav-item-signout']"))   
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(ele2));
ele2.click();
```

Comment: Thanks. I have tried it. But I see the problem is it is clicking on the first element element1 which is "Account and lists", but the page control is moving to Account instead of opening the flyout menu.  How to make the code click on the arrow and make the flyout clickable?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the click() method try this :

```
      WebElement element1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//header/div[@id='navbar']/div[@id='nav-belt']/div[3]/div[1]/a[1]/span[1]"));
  element1.sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='nav-item-signout']")).sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);
```

And instead of RETURN you can also try ENTER

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your response. I tried your code. But no luck. Now I get ElementNotInteractable Exception. Have you tried this code yourself? And has it anything to do with the browser that we are trying to automate? M trying in chrome.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code in which mover hover is implemented so it will hover the menu then you can click for sign-out.

```
WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.id("nav-link-accountList-nav-line-1"));
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(ele).perform();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='nav`enter code here`-item-signout']/span")).click();
```